# need an if, if_else, or for statement to replace unwanted numbers in data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr

Using R, what ifelse, if_else, if, for, or other statements should be used on a data.frame to find the negative numbers and replace them with the positive number 0.001?  Said another way, replace all negative numbers in the data.frame with the positive number 0.001.  A base R, plyr or dplyr function would work.

```
set.seed(1)

dfTest <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(c(-10:99), 7, rep = TRUE)))
```

In MS-Excel, the code might be `=if(x<0, 0.001, x)`.  There are several R examples for lists, just not many applicable for data.frames.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you don't need to use `ifelse()`, this will do the job:

```
dfTest[dfTest < 0] <- 0.001
#result
  X1     X2 X3     X4 X5
1 19 62.000 74 13.000 85
2 30 59.000 44 61.000 27
3 53  0.001 68  3.000 43
4 89 12.000 99 19.000 55
5 12  9.000 31 32.000 44
6 88 65.000 75  0.001 10
7 93 32.000 92 32.000 81
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Just use this.

dftest[dftest < 0] <- 0.001